# Match and replace depending on the regex pattern in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds

I have not been able to deploy a working process to use multiple regex patterns to match and replace the following patterns of names. I need to extract the last name, first name, middle initial or fill it with white space, and place commas between them Examples:

In:

- "HILL,ADAM APRN"
- "SMITH,JOHN B APRN"
- "JONES-WILSON,ROBERT APRN"

Out:

- "HILL,ADAM, ,APRN"
- "SMITH,JOHN,B,APRN"
- "JONES-WILSON,ROBERT, ,APRN"

The procedure I used stopped on the first name

Any assistance would greatly be appreciated.

Thank you - Matt

Comment: Is regexp is really necessary? You can split your strings with split(' ') spaces and then join it back width comma .join(',') and you will get result you need.

Comment: See [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r8v4b33n/1/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really need to use a regular expression, `(\w+(?:-\w+)?),(\w+)\s(?:([a-zA-Z]{1})\s)?(\w+)` will give you the captures that you need.

However, it would be much easier to use the `split` function like...

```
var name = "HILL,ADAM APRN";
var newName = name.split(/[ ,]/).join(',')
```

Comment: How would I add the white space when the middle initial is not present? i.e. "HILL,ADAM, ,APRN"

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = "HILL,ADAM APRN";
var blocks = str.match(/ /g).length;
var nuStr = (blocks==1 ? (str.replace(/ /, ', ,')) : (str.replace(/ /g, ',')));
```